# Dismiss View Controller when it was called by "performsegue"?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I have three view controllers: `Main`, `VC1`, and `VC2`. Whenever the app launches the delegate method defines which VC will display, whether it will be `Main` or `VC1`.

The app launches with `VC1`, and when a button is pressed it `[performSegueWithIdentifier]` to `VC2`, **but** when I press the logout button in `VC2` I want to release `VC1` and `VC2` from memory and display the `Main` view controller.

I also use navigation controller and storyboard. When the app is initialized the `didFinishLaunching` method will decide which view controller will be displayed, `Main` or `VC1`.

```
firstVC = Home||VC1

if(firstVC == VC1){
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier=@"" sender=self];
    //IT WILL OPEN THE VC2
}
```

In `VC2`, if I want to logout it needs to go to home. I need to release the `VC1` and `Main` from memory. (If I use `performSegue` it will not release the view controller, so it will keep running in the background wasting memory.) If I want to go back it needs to go back to `VC1`.

Comment: You should add more information - storyboard, app delegate, ...

Comment: I cant use images! Sorry ;/

Comment: Are you using a UINavigationController?

Comment: @GabrielAraujo In OSX, you can take screenshot with Cmd+Sht+4. Use this and append screeshot.

Comment: Yes, I do use navigation controller, I created my own navigation controller Class..

Comment: I cant post a image here because I do not have enough points